# What's the best way to secure soffit that joins a roofline?

Tags: soffit

I have a roofline similar to this.

[image: this picture].

Just above the porch column, there is a roofline that joins the main roofline. On my home, birds have started to push up on the soffit and make their way into my attic. I'm assuming this is how mice keep getting into my attic as well. Is there supposed to be some sort of support behind the soffit to keep it firm against the shingles?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say much from the very distant photo, but I'd guess that there's no metal channel against the roofing (shingles). That would prevent all but the burliest of birds and rodents from shimmying under.

The wall has a channel for the soffit to slip into, and that channel should wrap down the slope to the backside of the fascia.

Or, work in some lumber, fastened at the wall and fascia, to stiffen things. Don't puncture any existing roofing.

Answer (score 0):

Someone didn't install that correctly; it should not be able to be lifted up by a mouse or bird! If I undersand this correctly the problem is here:
[image]

If you happen to have any leftover soffit channel (or you can find it at a store) then by all means use it! But if not, then a 2x4 will work. If you can nail a metal chanel or (pressure treated) 2x4 to the roof behind the soffit, I would think that would solve the issue. You could also use a blob of tar on the bottom of the channel or 2x4 to ensure that there are no leaks due to wind blown rain or ice dams.

You might be thinking, if I put a hole in my shingles, then I will have a leak. But to that I say, trust the tar.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't nail anything to the roof there. Chances are the shingles are (correctly) slid up under the overhang. Fasten something in to stiffen the soffit, but don't damage the shingles.

Comment: there's a roof above the soffit, and above the proposed 2x4 support.

Comment: Yep, but there's also wind-blown rain and ice dams. ;)

Comment: If its a concern, put some tar on the (pressure treated) 2x4 (facing the shingles) before nailing it into the shingles.

Comment: Then you have a problem when it comes time to re-roof. I agree with your fix, just not with how you suggest that it gets fastened in place.

Comment: I suppose that you could use bolts... but I would prefer to encounter nails when I am taking shingles (or whatever) off with my roofing shovel. That way I don't need to go get a wrench to remove it.